# Selected cell hides the cells UITextView subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My Tableview cells expand when tapped, to show more information in 3 UITextViews.

But the cell changes color (as i want it to), and this hides the UITextViews, but not the other subviews as you can see in the image below.(orange lines indicate the textviews).

Changing the color of the textview background makes no difference.
What could i try?

[image]
EDIT ------ new image with TextFields.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that textviews place correctly? I see no text under orange lines.

Comment: Hi, i added another image with colors for clarification... the colors makes no difference. Its as if a new view is placed on top of the UITextViews, but not all the other subviews

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issues caused by `UITableViewCell` selection. When you select cell it changes `backgroundColor` on all subviews. To prevent this you have two options:

1) Subclass `UITableViewCell` and set color to subviews in:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

2) Setup color in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isSelected]) {
        UIView *view = [cell viewWithTag:TEXTFIELD_TAG];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i used the 2nd approach and it works. However, if i select a cell and scroll until the selected cell is out of the view, then it is no longer selected when it re-enters, and therefor doesn't have the backgroundcolor?

Comment: You can try to implement similar logic in `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` to be sure that all your colors setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If i have not misunderstood the question then You can try adding all these three text view in one  uiview(container) . Then on didselect table view cell change the background color of that container view. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it feels like there should be a less hackish way of fixing this

Answer (score 0):

Have your cell selection style to none and override setSelected method of tableView cell to change background color of cell.

{

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

}

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell

-(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    //--
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = (selected) ? [UIColor grayColor]:[UIColor whiteColor];
}

@end
```